# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid tables

Tags: java, android, sqlite

The error occurs when the app starts.

Tried to define:

```
queryBuilder.setTables(Constants.NOTES_TABLE);
```

but that gives an error saying

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column:

The complete error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid tables
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.findEditTable(SQLiteDatabase.java:973)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:400)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:294)
    at com.hackathon.hackmsit.data.NoteContentProvider.query(NoteContentProvider.java:70)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1000)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:214)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:478)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:422)
    at com.hackathon.hackmsit.data.NoteManager.getAllNotes(NoteManager.java:60)
    at com.hackathon.hackmsit.fragments.NoteListFragment.setupList(NoteListFragment.java:98)
    at com.hackathon.hackmsit.fragments.NoteListFragment.onCreateView(NoteListFragment.java:54)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1026)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1572)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:330)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:511)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6057)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5287) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699) 
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:114)
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.Drawer result = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        result = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withToolbar(mToolbar)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.title_home).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home).withIdentifier(1),
                        //new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.title_editor).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_edit).withIdentifier(2),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.title_settings).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_list).withIdentifier(2)

                )
                .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int i, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                        if (drawerItem != null && drawerItem instanceof Nameable){
                            String name = ((Nameable)drawerItem).getName().getText(MainActivity.this);
                            mToolbar.setTitle(name);
                        }

                        if (drawerItem != null){
                            int selectedScreen = drawerItem.getIdentifier();
                            switch (selectedScreen){
                                case 1:
                                    //go to List of Notes
                                    openFragment(new NoteListFragment(), "Notes");
                                    break;
                                /*case 2:
                                    //go the editor screen
                                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NoteEditorActivity.class));*/
                                case 2:
                                    //go to settings screen, yet to be added
                                    //this will be your home work
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Settings Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .withOnDrawerListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
                        KeyboardUtil.hideKeyboard(MainActivity.this);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDrawerSlide(View view, float v) {
                    }
                })
                .withFireOnInitialOnClick(true)
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                .build();
        if (savedInstanceState == null){
            result.setSelection(1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void openFragment(final Fragment fragment, String title){
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

NoteContentProvider.java:

```
public class NoteContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    private static final String BASE_PATH_NOTE = "notes";
    private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.hackathon.hackmsit.data.provider";
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + BASE_PATH_NOTE);
    private static final int NOTE = 100;
    private static final int NOTES = 101;

    private static final UriMatcher URI_MATCHER = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    static {
        URI_MATCHER.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH_NOTE, NOTES);
        URI_MATCHER.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH_NOTE + "/#", NOTE);
    }

    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    private void checkColumns(String[] projection) {
        if (projection != null) {
            HashSet<String> request = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(projection));
            HashSet<String> available = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(Constants.COLUMNS));
            if (!available.containsAll(request)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown columns in projection");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());

        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return (db == null)? false:true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        //queryBuilder.setTables(Constants.NOTES_TABLE);
        checkColumns(projection);

        int type = URI_MATCHER.match(uri);
        switch (type){
            case NOTE:
                //there is not to do if the query is for the table
                break;
            case NOTES:
                queryBuilder.appendWhere(Constants.COLUMN_ID + " = " + uri.getLastPathSegment());
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        int type = URI_MATCHER.match(uri);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Long id;
        switch (type){
            case NOTES:
                id = db.insert(Constants.NOTES_TABLE, null, values);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return Uri.parse(BASE_PATH_NOTE + "/" + id);
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        int type = URI_MATCHER.match(uri);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int affectedRows;
        switch (type) {
            case NOTES:
                affectedRows = db.delete(Constants.NOTES_TABLE, selection, selectionArgs);
                break;

            case NOTE:
                String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                    affectedRows = db.delete(Constants.NOTES_TABLE, Constants.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id, null);
                } else {
                    affectedRows = db.delete(Constants.NOTES_TABLE, Constants.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id + " and " + selection, selectionArgs);
                }
                break;

            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return affectedRows;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        int type = URI_MATCHER.match(uri);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int affectedRows;
        switch (type) {
            case NOTES:
                affectedRows = db.update(Constants.NOTES_TABLE, values, selection, selectionArgs);
                break;

            case NOTE:
                String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                    affectedRows = db.update(Constants.NOTES_TABLE, values, Constants.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id, null);
                } else {
                    affectedRows = db.update(Constants.NOTES_TABLE, values, Constants.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id + " and " + selection, selectionArgs);
                }
                break;

            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return affectedRows;
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "notes.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_NOTE = "create table "
            + Constants.NOTES_TABLE
            + "("
            + Constants.COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + Constants.COLUMN_TITLE + " text not null, "
            + Constants.COLUMN_CONTENT + " text not null, "
            + Constants.COLUMN_MODIFIED_TIME + " integer not null, "
            + Constants.COLUMN_CREATED_TIME + " integer not null " + ");";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_NOTE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Constants.NOTES_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Manifest entry:

```
<provider
        android:name=".data.NoteContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.hackathon.hackmsit.data.provider"
        android:exported="false" />
```

Edit:

Constants.java:

```
public class Constants {

public static final String NOTES_TABLE = "notes";

public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
//public final static String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
public static final String COLUMN_CONTENT = "content";
public static final String COLUMN_MODIFIED_TIME = "modified_time";
public static final String COLUMN_CREATED_TIME = "created_time";


public static final String[] COLUMNS = {
        Constants.COLUMN_ID,
        Constants.COLUMN_TITLE,
        Constants.COLUMN_CONTENT,
        Constants.COLUMN_MODIFIED_TIME,
        Constants.COLUMN_CREATED_TIME
};
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column:

At First Modify your `CREATE TABLE` Statement

```
   String CREATE_TABLE_NOTE = "CREATE TABLE " + Constants.NOTES_TABLE + "("
                + Constants.COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + Constants.COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT Default 'Unknown', "
                + Constants.COLUMN_CONTENT + " TEXT Default 'Unknown', "
                + Constants.COLUMN_MODIFIED_TIME + " INTEGER, "
                + Constants.COLUMN_CREATED_TIME + " INTEGER )";
```

Then **`Un-install old App & Run`** Again .

Comment: I still get the same error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid tables

Comment: why `//queryBuilder.setTables(Constants.NOTES_TABLE);` ?

Comment: I commented that because it gave me this error: Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: notes (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, content, created_time FROM notes WHERE (_id = notes)

Comment: where is `COLUMN_MODIFIED_TIME ` ?

Comment: That should have been in the Constants.java file, updated the post, still the same error: Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: notes (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, content, modified_time, created_time FROM notes WHERE (_id = notes)

Comment: @Paradigm okay wait .checking your query.

Comment: The problem is the WHERE clause "_id=notes" is invalid.  There is no column named "notes".

Comment: @Paradigm you can use `id` instead of `_id`

Comment: The expression in the WHERE clause can only use literal constants and columns that are named in the projection.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand the change that I should make.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I did a makeshift solution and changed: `queryBuilder.appendWhere(Constants.COLUMN_ID + " = " + uri.getLastPathSegment());` to this: `queryBuilder.appendWhere(Constants.COLUMN_ID + " = " + Constants.COLUMN_ID);`. Seems to be working, but don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: @Paradigm Glad to hear .Move ahead .I tried to help you

Comment: @Paradigm culprit is `appendWhere` :P